# Is there a simple method to get back the start menu, icons and task bar on the pc's screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors

What can I do to recover the icons, start menu and task bar so make my pc work again? Is there a combination of the keyboard letters and figures?

I tried to set a second image on the tv and I selected the "force the tv" choice.A disaster happened because the screen of the pc monitor has now only the theme image,without any start, icons or task bar icons.The mouse can only show me "arrange icons,propertiesand Nividia with 2 options:tv and ..." which do not work. What can i do to return to the former satus as i feel that the computer works but no image is on display.I am a beginner user of computers and I need help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your "primary" desktop is stuck on the TV. Is everything still gone if you unplug the TV? If you're on Windows 7, try pressing <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selecting "computer only". Or, try opening the properties when you right click and changing your display settings. You need to somehow get the computer screen to be your primary display again.

Comment: That is a better answer than mine. I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like it stopped explorer from running. You could try:

> Ctrl+Alt+Del
>
> (if you're in Windows 7 or Vista then:) Click
>   start Task Manager
>
> (if you're in XP the task manager should just pop up)
>
> Go to the Applications tab and click the
>   'New Task...' button in the bottom right hand corner
>
> Type in explorer.exe and hit enter